# Purge and reinstall Linux 3.19.0-31 (on 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I'm having issues with Linux 3.19.0-31 booting option, it gets completely stuck at boot. At first I thought it was due to the `proposed` repo breaking things, but removing it and all the packages that came through it did not help.

How may I purge all kernel packages and have them all reinstalled?

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-generic-lts-vivid
linux-generic-lts-vivid:
  Installed: 3.19.0.30.17
  Candidate: 3.19.0.30.17
  Version table:
 *** 3.19.0.30.17 0
        500 http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ dpkg -l | grep '3.19.0-31'
    ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-31                               3.19.0-31.35~14.04.1                                all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
    ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic                       3.19.0-31.35~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    ii  linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic                         3.19.0-31.35~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic                   3.19.0-31.35~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: @mchid I do. Your point being?

Comment: So you dont get stuck at boot. What's wrong with sudo apt-get purge?

Comment: @mchid I'm not stuck at boot—I'm posting this from the very system—the Linux kernel version I mentioned is the one getting stuck.

Comment: @A.B. ... I do see `linux-generic-lts-vivid` on the installed package lists...

Comment: Yes, but this package installs 3.19.0-30

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic-lts-vivid`

Comment: @A.B. There ye go.

Comment: You should remove the packages for the version 3.19.0-31

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -l | grep '3.19.0-31'`

Comment: @A.B. Edited those in. So remove every package starting with `linux` and includes the version string?

Comment: Remove all listed packages for version 3.19.0-31

Comment: @A.B., what if I were to force removal of all kernel packages? Would it break my system or would `apt-get` automagically add those to my ugrade queues?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge linux*-3\.19\.0-31*` and `sudo apt-get install linux*-3\.13\.0-33*`

Comment: Remove only the following `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.19.0-31 linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic`

Comment: `linux-generic-lts-vivid` is installed and therefore kernel `3.19.0.30.17`

Comment: @A.B., already purged those. `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` doesn't suggest any newer kernel. I was asking about removing *all* kernel packages so system could reinstall it and get rid of any configuration error. But I probably don't need to do it.

Comment: @LittleByBlue, tried your `purge` command, but that regex doesn't work (tried it with `-30` since already removed `-31`). See above command about installing that version.

Comment: I would say, that's a bad idea. You can reinstall the kernel via `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic-lts-vivid` but that's not necessary if the kernel works.

Comment: @A.B. Thanks for all the help. Might you do the honor of posting an answer so I can accept it? Just make points out of commands to list the packages to purge and the purge command itself.

Comment: @A.B. Eh, doesn't hurt to try. (I myself tried `linux*3.19.0-31*`, didn't work either) **:P** Since `-y` flag is absent, I can check what packages regex has selected before deciding to do it.

Comment: @A.B. using RegEx is completly save, (  _if you do not make mistakes_  ) __;)__  by the way  reputation is not a sooo clear indicator for knowledge.

Comment: @A.B. `yes "y"|sudo apt-get autoremove --purge linux*-3\.19\.0-31*` would be dangerous....

Comment: @LittleByBlue sorry, you're right. that was arrogant. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel version `3.19.0-31` isn't available in Trusty (perhaps in the proposed repository).
The package `linux-generic-lts-vivid` installs  the current kernel version `3.19.0.30.17`.

Therefore remove the packages for `3.19.0-31`.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.19.0-31 linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic
```

More isn't necessary, because `linux-generic-lts-vivid` is already installed on your system with the kernel version `3.19.0.30.17`.